# Pass Multiple parameter content to RequestBody in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

> I have multiple String value I want to pass inside Request body ,but
> request body allow only one string value to pass inside RequestBody.
> But I want multiple value How it possible. For your reference I post
> my code what I tried for this

```
private JsonObject gateWayToken(ThirdPartyPaymentGatewayToken thirdPartyPaymentGatewayToken ,ObjectWriter ow  ) throws IOException{
            String brandwiseBearerToken="";
            String brandwiseURL="";
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
            
                String thirdPartyPaymentGatewayTokenJson = ow.writeValueAsString(thirdPartyPaymentGatewayToken);
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType,thirdPartyPaymentGatewayTokenJson );
                Request request = new Request.Builder().url(brandwiseURL).post(body)
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").addHeader("Bearer", brandwiseBearerToken)
                        .build();
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
                return new Gson().fromJson(responseBody.string(), JsonObject.class);
        }
```

> But I do not want to pass single String value
> I want to pass multiple string value inside below line

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType,thirdPartyPaymentGatewayTokenJson );
```

> also I want to pass Dynamic value inside above line, not to use hard
> code line.

Answer (score 1):

The body can only contain on string.

So you simply can concatenate the strings:

```
RequestBody.create(mediaType +" "+ thirdPartyPaymentGatewayTokenJson);
```